# How can I draw loose arrow on 90 degree ends?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing arrows using `-|` but it draws sharp turn with 90 degree.
Instead, I want to loose 90 degree as using following curved arrow format style.

[image]

[image]

---

my code:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    arr/.style = {-stealth},
    N/.style = {draw,
        font=\scriptsize,
        align=left,
        inner sep=3pt
    },
    ]
    \node (n1) [N, text width=0.5cm] at (1.2, 4) {\vspace*{-0.8mm}{hello}};
    \node (n2) [N, text width=0.6cm] at (3, 4) {\vspace*{-0.8mm}{world}};
    \draw[arr] (n1.north) -- ([yshift=2mm] n1.north) -| (n2.north) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Here I was not able to loose the arrow on its sharp end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `rounded corners=<inset>`. The `<inset>` describes how big the corner is. See section 14.5 Rounding Corners of the [TikZ manual](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

For the height of the node, you can use `text height` (and, if needed, `text depth`).

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    arr/.style = {-stealth,
        rounded corners=7,},
    N/.style = {draw,
        font=\scriptsize,
        align=left,
        inner sep=3pt
    },
    ]
    \node (n1) [N, text height=1.8mm] at (1.2, 4) {hello};
    \node (n2) [N, text height=1.8mm] at (3, 4) {world};
    \draw[arr] (n1.north) -- ([yshift=4mm] n1.north) -| (n2.north) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Zarko commented, you can also use `minimum height`.
If all the nodes have the same minimum height, you can put this option in the `N` style.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    arr/.style = {-stealth,
        rounded corners=7,
        },
    N/.style = {draw,
        font=\scriptsize,
        align=left,
        inner sep=3pt, 
        minimum height=1.8mm
        },
    ]
    \node (n1) [N] at (1.2, 4) {hello};
    \node (n2) [N] at (3, 4) {world};
    \draw[arr] (n1.north) -- ([yshift=4mm] n1.north) -| (n2.north) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may move `text height=...` from nodes option to definition of their style. Maybe be beter to define ˛`minimal height` ... anyway, +1!

Comment: @Zarko Added your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

just add the option `rounded corners` in `\draw` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        arr/.style = {-stealth},
        N/.style = {draw,
            font=\scriptsize,
            align=left,
            inner sep=3pt
        },
        ]
        \node (n1) [N, text width=0.5cm] at (1.2, 4) {\vspace*{-0.8mm}{hello}};
        \node (n2) [N, text width=0.6cm] at (3, 4) {\vspace*{-0.8mm}{world}};
        \draw[arr,rounded corners] (n1.north) -- ([yshift=2mm] n1.north) -| (n2.north) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```